# How to select specific content between second and third comma using Regex in sublime text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

Hi everyone I'm trying to select the content in between the second and third comma using regex

This is my content

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('Alejandro', 'dislike', '', 20, 'otro nombre')
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('Jando', 'like', '', 30, 'wtf')
```

As you can see between second and third comma are just single quotes `''` and I want to selected them using regex because I need to modify like 5000 lines in sublime text 3, I hope you can help me, I tried with no success `,(.*){2}` I know I'm wrong, I have no experience with regex

Note: No all time will be single quotes `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 \bVALUES\s(?:[^\n,]*,){2}\h*\K[^,\n]+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/j6deon/3)

**Explanation**

```
\b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  VALUES                   'VALUES'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\n,]*                  any character except: '\n' (newline),
                             ',' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \h*                      horizontal whitespace (0 or more times 
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator (discarding text matched so far)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^,\n]+                  any character except: ',', '\n' (newline)
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Another attempt:

```
\bVALUES\s*\((?:\s*'(?:''|[^'])*'\s*,){2}\s*\K'(?:''|[^'])*'
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/j6deon/4)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  VALUES                   'VALUES'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        ' char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ''                       ''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']                     any character except: '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator (discarding text matched so far)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''                       '\'\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']                     any character except: '''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```

Comment: I edited the question, can you check it again please?

Comment: This works perfect, thank you so much for you help and explanation :)